# How to open calendar format using html codes?

Tags: html, calendar, format

Can anyone please tell me about how to open calendar pop up format in html? So that the user could select date, month and year from the calendar in a form like course registration form.

How to design the form in html for selecting the dd-mm-yyyy?

Please give me suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 offers this facility natively: [HTML5 date picker](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date).

If your target browser(s) do not yet support that, you have to implement it yourself in JavaScript, for example, by using one of the available `date picker script`s. Use the search engine of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

You cannot do it with HTML Only. Need the aid of Javascript to do it.

Comment: Thanks to HTML5, it can be done without any scripting: http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html#type-date - though, browser support is still "a bit limited".

Comment: I didn't know HTML5 offers Datepickers. Thanks for the add ... but frankly I don't think it's mature enough to be used.

Comment: HTML5 is still to new to rely only on it, except for limited users communities.  However, it would be a good idea prepare to use it, and perhaps use it when you known HTML5 is supported.